# How to make position auto-increment and avoid getting duplicate results in listview?

Tags: android, mysql, listview, android-arrayadapter

I have a listview and a custom adapter, I get 2 results both different but only one is being placed twice. How do I make it so they are both shown? Here is my adapter, where I believe the problem lies:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
public final class SearchAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ProblemInfo> {

Context context;
ArrayList<ProblemInfo> problem;
LayoutInflater vi;
  int resource;

  public SearchAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<ProblemInfo> data) {
      super(context, resource, data);

      vi = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
      problem = data;

      }
  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

   final ViewHolder holder;
   if(convertView ==null){
    convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.searchvehiclerow,parent,false);
    holder = new ViewHolder();

    holder.tvMilage = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_txtMilage);
    holder.tvProblem = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_txtProblem);

    convertView.setTag(holder);

   } else {
    holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();

   }
   ProblemInfo ProblemInfo = problem.get(position);
   holder.tvProblem.setText(ProblemInfo.getProbdesc());
   holder.tvMilage.setText(ProblemInfo.getMilage());

   return convertView;

 }
 static class ViewHolder {
  public TextView tvMilage;
   public TextView tvProblem;
  }
}
```

here is my pull from the database;

```
 public class ProblemInfoAsynTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean>{
 @Override
  protected Boolean doInBackground(String... urls) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 String resultprob = "";
 InputStream isrProb = null;
try{

HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(urls[0]);  
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
if(status == 200){
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
isrProb = entity.getContent();

try{
     BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(isrProb,"iso-8859-1"),8);
     StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
     String line = null;
     while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
             sb.append(line + "\n");
     }
     isrProb.close();

     resultprob=sb.toString();
}
catch(Exception e){
     Log.e("log_tag", "Error  converting result "+e.toString());
 }
 JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(resultprob);

for(int i=0; i<jArray.length();i++){
ProblemInfo problem = new ProblemInfo();
JSONObject json = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

problem.setMilage(json.getInt("milage"));
problem.setProbdesc(json.getString("problem_description"));
problem.setId(json.getLong("problem_id"));
probList.add(problem);
   }
return true;
}

} catch (ClientProtocolException e){
  e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e){
  e.printStackTrace();
} catch (JSONException e){
  e.printStackTrace();
}


return false;
}
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {

super.onPostExecute(result);
if(result == false){


}else {
SearchAdapter probAdapter = new SearchAdapter(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,probList);
searchView.setAdapter(probAdapter);
}
}
```

Here is my array list

```
public class ProblemInfo {

    private static int milage;
    private static String probdesc;
    private long id;
    String milage2;

    public ProblemInfo()
    {

    }

    public void setMilage(int milage) {
        ProblemInfo.milage = milage;
    }

    public String getProbdesc() {
        return probdesc;
    }

    public void setProbdesc(String probdesc) {
        ProblemInfo.probdesc = probdesc;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getMilage()
    {
        milage2 = Integer.toString(milage);
    return milage2;
    }

}
```

I have milage2 to string so that I can print it into a textbox I thought It was a problem before so I wanted to make sure it wouldn't be

Comment: Are you sure you're getting non-duplicated values from the database? try to print the values out before adding the to the list using Log and let me know!

Comment: yes im sure its getting non duplicated values from database, I just went over it 3 times making sure its getting the 2 different values, it keeps using only the 2nd - last value.

Comment: see it does it for 2 results but does not do the first one, in my opinion I need a loop but I don't know where to put it...

Comment: I'm really not sure what the problem might be, I'm using the same classes and methods and it's working fine, that's why I suspected that the problem is related to the way you pull data from server. the only difference is that I use a constructor instead of setters, so you create an instance of that helper class, pass all the value, add it to an array list then use addAll to add it to the adapter. Then I use ProblemInfo ProblemInfo = getItem(position); try it out.

Comment: could you show me what you wrote in code please, im new to this and don't know where or what to do to be honest. sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified your code, I didn't test it myself, but give it a try..

**ProblemInfo.java**

```
public class ProblemInfo {

private static int milage;
private static String probdesc;
private long id;
String milage2;

public ProblemInfo(String probdesc, long id,String  milage2)
{

 this.probdesc = probdesc;
 this.id = id;
 this.milage2 = milage2;  
}   

public String getProbdesc() {
    return probdesc;
}
public long getId() {
    return id;
}    
public String getMilage()
{
    milage2 = Integer.toString(milage);
    return milage2;
}
```

}

In **ProblemInfoAsynTask**
replace

```
problem.setMilage(json.getInt("milage"));
problem.setProbdesc(json.getString("problem_description"));
problem.setId(json.getLong("problem_id"));
probList.add(problem);
```

with

```
probList.add(new ProblemInfo(json.getString("problem_description"), json.getLong("problem_id")),    json.getInt("milage") );
```

And replace

```
SearchAdapter probAdapter = new    SearchAdapter(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,probList);
searchView.setAdapter(probAdapter);
```

with

```
SearchAdapter probAdapter = new SearchAdapter(getApplicationContext());
searchView.setAdapter(probAdapter);
probAdapter.addAll(probList);
probAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

in **SearchAdapter.java**

replace

```
  public SearchAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<ProblemInfo> data) {
  super(context, resource, data);

  vi = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
  problem = data;

  }
```

with

```
public SearchAdapter(Context context) {
  super(context, R.layout.yourlyaout);

  vi = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

  }
```

and use

```
ProblemInfo ProblemInfo = getItem(position);
```

instead of

```
ProblemInfo ProblemInfo = problem.get(position);
```

**Update**

```
ArrayList<ProblemInfo> probList = new ArrayList<ProblemInfo>();
```

I hope that will work, if you face any problem, let me know.

Comment: gets a ThreadPoolExecutor error here

probList.add(new ProblemInfo(json.getString("problem_description"), json.getLong("problem_id")),    json.getInt("milage") );

with the code you gave. also if i dont comment out 

probList.notifyDataSetChanged(); 

there is a red error under notifyDataSetChanged, the error says its undefined for the type ArrayList<ProblemInfo>

Comment: Sorry, typo mistake, obviously, it should be probAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); ..

Comment: ill test this later and let you know, im finishing some other parts of the app and not doing async till app is done so tomorrow ill test it